# Nhibernate Hql query retrieve DateTime empty

Tags: nhibernate, datetime, hql

I need hql query for retrieving objects with an empty value in a datetime property

Something like that

from Users u where u.LastLogon is empty

LastLogon is a DateTime? property, datetime in the MS Sql Table

How can you do that?

Comment: For DateTime? is null, but for DateTime properties should be the minimum value supported in MS SQL, but I don't know how should be for other databases than MS SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`from Users u where u.LastLogon is null` should work.